# How to display drawings from ArcGIS on Google Maps using JavaScript or PHP?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, javascript, google-maps, php

my client has ArcGIS installed on his PC
 and he has designed roads, hospitals, houses, and parks of a specific area in ArcGIS
 he needs his system online.

challenging task for me is how can I get all drawing information from his ArcGIS that I can show that same drawing on google map using javascript or php or whatever
 I searched it but I am not satisfied yet.

there is also a solution of creating ArcGIS Server, but that will be my 2nd priority.
 I am thinking to somehow export all drawing information from ArcGIS and feed it to google map.
 bcz there will be no frequent changes in drawing he has. (means drawings are static and not changing frequently.)

Comment: Would KML files fit your needs? https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut

Comment: Does it have to be in Google specifically or can it be served on any online web map interface?

Answer (score 1):

This is a two step process:

1. Using **ArcGIS for Desktop** export a single **[Layer to KML](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00120000004n000000)** or a whole **[Map to KML](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00120000004p000000)**
2. Display your **[KML in Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport)** - perhaps using **[Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml)**.